# Segementation fault in implemetation of DFS of a matrix with Stack data stucture in CPP

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, stack, depth-first-search

I have been trying to solve D question of code forces round #648, the link to the question is as follow: [Question D](https://codeforces.com/contest/1365/problem/D)

My code follows the same description as in the tutorial:

I'm trying to do a depth-first search of the Maze(a nxm matrix), to check whether all **G** can be reached or not for cell[n][m].

My code is as follow:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n , m;
void DFS(char **Maze, int **found,stack <int> &si,stack <int> &sj)
{
    if(!si.empty() && !sj.empty())
    {
        int i,j;
        i = si.top();
        j = sj.top();
        si.pop();
        sj.pop();
        found[i][j] = 1;

        if(found[i][j+1]!=1 && Maze[i][j+1]!='#' && j!=m-1){
            si.push(i);
            sj.push(j+1);
        }
        if(found[i][j-1]!=1 && Maze[i][j-1]!='#' && j!=0){
            si.push(i);
            sj.push(j-1);
        }
        if(Maze[i+1][j]!=1 && Maze[i+1][j]!='#' && i!=n-1){
            si.push(i+1);
            sj.push(j);
        }
        if(Maze[i-1][j]!=1 && Maze[i-1][j]!='#' && i!=0){
            si.push(i-1);
            sj.push(j);
        }

        DFS(Maze,found,si,sj);
    }
    else
        return;
}

int main()
{ 
    int t,i,j,flag,G;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> n >> m;
        char **Maze = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
        int **found = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            Maze[i] = (char *)malloc(m*sizeof(char));
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                cin >> Maze[i][j];
        }

        flag = 0;
        G = 0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(Maze[i][j] == 'B')
                {
                    if(Maze[i][j+1] != 'G' && j!=m-1){
                        Maze[i][j+1] = '#';
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = 1;
                        i=n;
                        break;
                    }

                    if(Maze[i][j-1] != 'G' && j!=0){
                        Maze[i][j] = '#';
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = 1;
                        i=n;
                        break;
                    }

                    if(Maze[i+1][j] != 'G' && i!=n-1){
                        Maze[i+1][j] = '#';
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = 1;
                        i=n;
                        break;
                    }

                    if(Maze[i-1][j] != 'G' && i!=0){
                        Maze[i-1][j] = '#';
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = 1;
                        i=n;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(Maze[i][j] == 'G')
                    G++;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1 )
            cout << "No" << endl;
        else
        {
            if(G==0)
                cout << "Yes" << endl;
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    found[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
                    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                        found[i][j] = -1;
                }

                stack <int> si, sj;
                si.push(n-1);           
                sj.push(m-1);
                DFS(Maze,found,si,sj);

                flag = 0;
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                    {
                        if(Maze[i][j] == 'G' && found[i][j] == -1)
                        {
                            flag = 1;
                            i = n;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(flag == 1)
                    cout << "No" << endl;
                else
                    cout << "Yes" << endl;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the stack data structure to keep track of the nodes/cell of the maze/matrix that I'm traversing.

But there has been a Segmentation fault in this stack implementation, which on debugging shows as:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554f9b in DFS (Maze=0x55555576c280, found=0x55555576c2a0, 
    si=std::stack wrapping: std::deque with 1 element = {...}, 
    sj=std::stack wrapping: std::deque with 1 element = {...})
    at solveMaze.cpp:25
25          if(Maze[i+1][j]!=1 && Maze[i+1][j]!='#' && i!=n-1){
(gdb)
```

I have used stack data structure the first time, so don't know much about it but I'm sure, not to use alternate implementation for this question like vectors or arrays.

Thanks in advance for any minor updates!!!

Comment: Its due to I'm trying to access cell of matrix which is not in memory like Maze[i][j] where i = n, like in **if(Maze[i+1][j]!=1 && Maze[i+1][j]!='#' && i!=n-1){
            si.push(i+1);
            sj.push(j);
        } **  but still since I'm checking the out of bound condition of **i!n-1** as **i+1** won't be accessible. But as we know that conditions are checked in right to left fashion. So the out of bound condition(memory overflow) on **Maze[i+1][j]** should not be encountered!! since it won't be checked once last condition came **false**

Comment: Conditions are checked from left to right.